# How to take data from SQL, list in PHP as a variable and then send it back to SQL as a $_POST?

Tags: php, sql, html

I hope I can explain this good enough...

I currently have data stored in a SQL table called 'client', I have taken this information that is stored there and it is currently displaying on a PHP page.

Now that this data is taken from the SQL to the PHP, do I need to store it somehow in order to POST it back to the database?  If this is the case I am not should how this is done...

```
<?php
include 'includes/config.php';
$sel = "SELECT car_name FROM cars WHERE car_id = '$_GET[id]'";
$rs = $conn->query($sel);
$rws = $rs->fetch_assoc();
?>              

<?php echo 'Your Car: '.$rws['car_name'];?><br>
```

From the snippet of code, this is included within a  as there is other information that is being gathered on the page.  The SQL code SELECT gathers the information and the PHP displays it fine, I am now trying to use the same information and send it back to the SQL database.

Thanks guys, I hope you can help.

Comment: Why do you need to "send back" the data that already exists in the database? You know that when you fetch data from a database, it still left in the database?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select data from database and display it in your app, you do not need to store same data into database. These data are persistent in DBS.
If you need to find a way how to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages, you can use session. Sessions are global variables.
Place `session_start();` in the beginning of your app.
Use:
`$_SESSION["car_name"] = $rws['car_name'];`

You can use `session_unset();` to remove all sessions in the end of app.